# iOS Change DNS Server from App without going into iPhone wifi settings

Tags: ios, dns

Is that possible to change DNS programmatically from App.

Instead of going into  Wifi Settings in IP Address in DNS in iPhone.

Comment: You cant without `Jailbreak`ing.

Comment: But how can i do this in jailbreak phone

Comment: Here you can find some help. https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers

Comment: Not getting any help from above mentioned headers to change DNS

Comment: That is complete iOS. You have to find responsible framework for network connections and hardware controls. You can ask apple if they are able to help on this topic. There are alot of chances that they will help because you can't publish such app on the store. It must be an B2B app.